# Conditional math based on checkbox status

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script with a simple formula:

```
Input 1 * Input 2 * Input 3 / 25 = result
```

How can I manipulate the value 25 if a checbox is checked?

For example, if a checkbox is checked, the input 1,2,3 should divide with 35 at the end instead of 25 and display the result divided by 35.

[Sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5uqkaavv/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    var divide = (document.getElementById('changeValue').checked ? 35 : 25);
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2 * myBox3 / divide;
    result.value = myResult.toFixed(2) + ' eggs';
}
```

Comment: p.s. Is there a way to append a text string inside the input after the result value. For example, 1,984 eggs. And also to limit the result to two decimals?

Comment: Added the word 'eggs' to the answer. Check this SO answer for correct rounding of numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript/25075575#25075575

Comment: Added the rounding from the SO answer.

Comment: For two decimals use `myResult.toFixed(2)`. Not sure where `Math.round10` even comes from.

Comment: You are right.  toFixed is a better / simpler option here. The Math.round10 method is from the SO question provided.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2 * myBox3 / 25;
```

for

```
var divisor = ((document.getElementById('changeValue').checked)?35:25);
var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2 * myBox3 / divisor ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic check to see if a checkbox is checked.

```
var isChecked = document.getElementById("changeValue").checked;  //get boolean for checked
var num = isChecked ? 35 : 25;  //ternary operation
```

References: [Conditional_Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding:

```
var value = (document.getElementById('changeValue').checked)?35:25;
```

Like that:

```
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var value = (document.getElementById('changeValue').checked)?35:25;
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2 * myBox3 / value;
    result.value = myResult;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;   
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result');   
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2 * myBox3 / 25;
    result.value = myResult;   

    //set initial state
     $('#changeValue').change(function() {
         if($(this).is(":checked")) {
          var myDivide = myBox1 * myBox2 * myBox3 / 35;
          return result.value = myDivide; 
         }     
     });
}
```